# Combine 2 series pandas - overwriting the NANs

Tags: python, pandas

If we have 2 series:

```
a = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, np.nan, 5, np.nan, np.nan])
b = pd.Series([np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 4, np.nan, 6, 7])
```

How can I get c, such that

```
a                 b             c
========          ========      =========
0    1.0          0    NaN      0    1.0     
1    2.0          1    NaN      1    2.0
2    3.0          2    NaN      2    3.0
3    NaN          3    4.0      3    4.0
4    5.0          4    NaN      4    5.0
5    NaN          5    6.0      5    6.0
6    NaN          6    7.0      6    7.0
```

where c is the overlap of a & b, if the value is not a NaN (it will always be the case)

Comment: `a.combine_first(b)`

Comment: Hmm, the `add(fill_value=0)` isn't in the dupe. I'll add that.

Comment: Or even `a.where(pd.notnull, b)` if we're just throwing options out there :)

Comment: @DSM; actually, the dupe does not specify that the NaNs are in mutually exclusive positions (like this question seems to claim). So, the `add(fill_value)` method will not work there. Do you still think they're duplicates?

Comment: @JonClements I came up with `a.mask(a.isnull(), b)`. I can tell you're getting good at this.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, your solution is marginally faster:

combine_first = 991 µs ± 28 µs per loop
mask = 923 µs ± 13.4 µs per loop

Comment: @AH Cheers, glad it worked. Go to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38152389/coalesce-values-from-2-columns-into-a-single-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe and upvote (or downvote) the answers if you could.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ done, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for not downvoting ;-)