# Add column from 2nd DataFrame based on comparison of two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

In simple terms, I'm trying to add columns `latitude` and `longitude` from `df1` to a smaller DataFrame called `df2` by comparing the values from their `air_id` and `hpg_id` columns:

[image]

The trick to add `latitude` and `longitude` to `df2` relies on how the comparison is made to `df1`, which could be one of 3 cases:

- When there is a match between `df2.air_id` AND `df1.air_hd`;
- When there is a match between `df2.hpg_id` AND `df1.hpg_hd`;
- When there is a match between both of them: `[df2.air_id, df2.hpg_id]` AND `[df1.air_hd, df1.hpg_id]`;

With that in mind, the expected result should be:

[image]

Notice how the `ignore_me` column from `df1` was left out of the resulting DataFrame.

Here is the code to setup the DataFrames:

```
data = { 'air_id'     : [ 'air1',     '', 'air3', 'air4', 'air2', 'air1' ], 
         'hpg_id'     : [ 'hpg1', 'hpg2',     '', 'hpg4',     '',     '' ], 
         'latitude'   : [  101.1,  102.2,    103,    104,    102, 101.1, ],
         'longitude'  : [     51,     52,     53,     54,     52,    51, ],
         'ignore_me'  : [     91,     92,     93,     94,     95,    96 ] }

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
display(df1)


data2 = { 'air_id'    : [     '',  'air2', 'air3', 'air1' ], 
          'hpg_id'    : [ 'hpg1',  'hpg2',     '',     '' ]  }

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
display(df2)
```

Unfortunately, I'm failing to use `merge()` for this task. My current result is a DataFrame with all columns from `df1` mostly filled with *NaNs*:

[image]

How can I copy these specific columns from `df1` using the rules above?

Comment: Is `hpg3` supposed to be in the `air_id` column? Is that a typo? I feel like your result doesn't make sense unless it's in the `hpg_id` column or am I missing something?

Comment: It's a typo! Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to accomplish what you're trying to do.

First use `merge()` twice. First on `air_id`, then on `hpg_id`. For both, ignore the trivial case when the key is an empty string.

```
result = df2\
    .merge(
        df1[df1['air_id']!=''].drop(['hpg_id'], axis=1), on=['air_id'], how='left'
    )\
    .merge(
        df1[df1['hpg_id']!=''].drop(['air_id'], axis=1), on=['hpg_id'], how='left'
    )

print(result)
#  air_id hpg_id  ignore_me_x  latitude_x  longitude_x  ignore_me_y  \
#0          hpg1          NaN         NaN          NaN           91   
#1   air2   hpg2         92.0       102.0         52.0           92   
#2          hpg3          NaN         NaN          NaN           93   
#
#   latitude_y  longitude_y  
#0         101           51  
#1         102           52  
#2         103           53
```

However, this creates duplicates for the columns you want. (I drop the other join key on each call to merge to avoid duplicate column names for those.)

We can coalesce these values by adapting one of the methods described on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38152389/coalesce-values-from-2-columns-into-a-single-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe).

```
cols = ['latitude', 'longitude']
colsx = list(map(lambda c: c+"_x", cols))  # list needed for python3
colsy = list(map(lambda c: c+"_y", cols))  # list needed for python3
result[cols] = pd.DataFrame(
    np.where(result[colsx].isnull() == True, result[colsy], result[colsx])
)
result = result[['air_id', 'hpg_id'] + cols]
print(result)
#  air_id hpg_id  latitude  longitude
#0          hpg1     101.0       51.0
#1   air2   hpg2     102.0       52.0
#2   air3            103.0       53.0
```

---

**UPDATE**

In the case where the merge produces duplicate entries, you can use [`pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html).

```
result = result.drop_duplicates()
```

Comment: @karlphillip are you using python3? If so you have to wrap the calls to `map` with `list` (I updated the answer). Here are working examples on repl.it: [python2 example](https://repl.it/repls/FuzzyObviousInstructions) and [python3 example](https://repl.it/repls/WeirdLinenSoftwareengineer).

Comment: Great! How does it compare against the other answers in terms of performance?

Comment: If you can update your question with an example case where it doesn't work, I can try to find a way to modify it.

Comment: @karlphillip A simple fix for this example would be to just add `result = result.drop_duplicates()` at the end. Let me know if that solves your larger issue and I'll update my answer.

Comment: Fantastic solution! On extreme cases where there is more than one entry with the same `air_id` or `hpg_id` and both occurrences have different latitude/longitude coordinates (for some weird reason), is add all the occurrences of that id (with different lat/lon coordinates) to the result table, which is absolutely great! In terms of performance, it took only 16s to process `df1` with **2343828** rows and `df2`  with 10 rows. It's pretty incredible, congratulations!

Answer (score 3):

Using sets and Numpy broadcasting to handle the matching of stuff... sprinkled with fairy dust

```
ids = ['air_id', 'hpg_id']
cols = ['latitude', 'longitude']

def true(s): return s.astype(bool)

s2 = df2.stack().loc[true].groupby(level=0).apply(set)
s1 = df1[ids].stack().loc[true].groupby(level=0).apply(set)

i, j = np.where((s1.values & s2.values[:, None]).astype(bool))

a = np.zeros((len(df2), 2), int)
a[i, :] = df1[cols].values[j]

df2.join(pd.DataFrame(a, df2.index, cols))

  air_id hpg_id  latitude  longitude
0          hpg1       101         51
1   air2   hpg2       102         52
2   hpg3              103         53
```

---

**Details**

`s2` looks like this

```
0          {hpg1}
1    {air2, hpg2}
2          {hpg3}
dtype: object
```

And `s1`

```
0    {air1, hpg1}
1          {hpg2}
2          {hpg3}
3    {air4, hpg4}
4          {air2}
dtype: object
```

The point is that we wanted to find if anything from that row matched with anything else in a row from the other data frame.  Now I can use broadcasting and `&`

```
s1.values & s2.values[:, None]

array([[{'hpg1'}, set(), set(), set(), set()],
       [set(), {'hpg2'}, set(), set(), {'air2'}],
       [set(), set(), {'hpg3'}, set(), set()]], dtype=object)
```

But empty sets evaluate to `False` in a boolean context so

```
(s1.values & s2.values[:, None]).astype(bool)

array([[ True, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False,  True],
       [False, False,  True, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

And now I can use `np.where` to show me where these `True`s are

```
i, j = np.where((s1.values & s2.values[:, None]).astype(bool))

print(i, j)

[0 1 1 2] [0 1 4 2]
```

Those are the the rows from `df2` and `df1` respectively.  But I don't need two row `1` so I create an empty array of the appropriate size with the expectations that I'll overwrite row `1`.  I fill these values with the lats and lons from `df1`

```
a = np.zeros((len(df2), 2), int)
a[i, :] = df1[cols].values[j]

a

array([[101,  51],
       [102,  52],
       [103,  53]])
```

I then wrap this in a `pd.DataFrame` and join as we see above.

Comment: For the rounding, use dtype float when creating `a`.  `a = np.zeros((len(df2), 2))`

Comment: I ended up selecting another answer as the official problem solver because of it's faster performance and robustness. Your solution took ~3min to process `df1` with **2343828** rows and `df2` with **10** rows. Nevertheless, I hope people can appreciate the great explanation you gave for this approach! I find it very educational and helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is one manual way without merges. It isn't efficient, but might be manageable if it performs adequately for your use case.

```
df1['lat_long'] = list(zip(df1['latitude'], df1['longitude']))

air = df1[df1['air_id'] != ''].set_index('air_id')['lat_long']
hpg = df1[df1['hpg_id'] != ''].set_index('hpg_id')['lat_long']

def mapper(row):
    myair, myhpg = row['air_id'], row['hpg_id']
    if (myair != '') and (myair in air):
        return air.get(myair)
    elif (myhpg != '') and (myhpg in hpg):
        return hpg.get(myhpg)
    elif (myair != '') and (myair in hpg):
        return hpg.get(myair)
    elif (myhpg != '') and (myhpg in air):
        return air.get(myhpg)
    else:
        return (None, None)

df2['lat_long'] = df2.apply(mapper, axis=1)
df2[['latitude', 'longitude']] = df2['lat_long'].apply(pd.Series)
df2 = df2.drop('lat_long', 1)

#   air_id hpg_id  latitude  longitude
# 0          hpg1       101         51
# 1   air2   hpg2       102         52
# 2   hpg3              103         53
```