# Compare the column of table and put result in another table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, metadata

I have a Dataframe which looks like this:

```
Date      Input         Val1        Val2
1-Dec      X             10           5
2-Dec      Y                          15
3-Dec      Z             4            5
4-Dec      A                          10
```

i want the output in such a way, that if Val1 is present in then in the output val1 will be diplayed otherwise it will take the Val2 in the output, so my output will be:

```
Date      Input         Val1        Val2            Output
1-Dec      X             10           5              10           
2-Dec      Y                          15             15            since Val1 is missing so took Val2 in output
3-Dec      Z             4            5              4  
4-Dec      A                          10             10            since Val1 is missing so took Val2 in output
```

i tred pd.Concat but it is not giving correct output

Comment: You can check this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38152389/coalesce-values-from-2-columns-into-a-single-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpliest is use [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df['Output'] = df['Val1'].fillna(df['Val2'])
```

Solution with testing missing values is [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['Output'] = np.where(df['Val1'].isna(), df['Val2'], df['Val1'])
```