# How to change values in certain column of DataFrame based on another DataFrame in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe called 'data':

```
USER   FIELD1
Jack        1
Jill        2
Kane        3
```

and a separate dataframe called 'ids' that serves to be used as a conversion table:

```
ID            ID_NEW
Jack        Jack_NEW
Jill        Jill_NEW
Tyler      TYLER_NEW
```

How can I iterate through 'data' to replace the USER value if it is found in the 'ids' dataframe while keeping values that are not found? To end up with something like:

```
USER           FIELD1
Jack_NEW            1
Jill_NEW            2
Kane                3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in a couple steps. First, you join the two DataFrames together on "USER = ID" using [pd.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html). This will leave nulls in "ID_NEW" where the dfs don't join, so then you bring in the "USER" values for those using [Series.combine_first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38152389/coalesce-values-from-2-columns-into-a-single-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe). Finally, you reassign column names and filter down to just the columns you want to keep.

```py
merged = pd.merge(data, ids, how="left", left_on="USER", right_on="ID")
merged["USER"] = merged["ID_NEW"].combine_first(merged["USER"])
data = merged[["USER", "FIELD1"]]
```

If you have a lot of columns in `data`, you could do `data = merged[data.columns]` at the end.

Comment: is there a way to do this without merging? maybe through an iterative fashion? my actual 'data' df has dozens of columns so it would be messy on the last step

Comment: Could you do `data = data[data.columns]` to easily subset? Merging is probably going to be the best practice solution here. I'm sure there are other ways to do it, but they'd be a little more convoluted.

Comment: not sure how to incorporate that. data=data[data.columns] seems like it won't do anything since you'd just be setting it equal to whatever columns are already existing

Comment: rewrote your solution a bit:

`merged = pd.merge(data, ids, how="left", left_on="USER", right_on="ID")
merged["USER"] = merged["ID_NEW"].combine_first(merged["USER"])
merged = merged.drop(['ID', 'ID_NEW'], axis=1)`

thanks again :)