# Creating another column in pandas df based on partially empty columns

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I want to create a third column in my pandas dataframe that is based on cols 1 and 2. They are always matching, but I want to make it so that the third column takes whichever value is available. If I just go off of id1, sometimes it is blank, so the third col will end up being blank as well. I want it so that it will take whichever one isn't blank to create the college name.

Original:

```
    id1     id2            
0   ID01   ID01             
1          ID03            
2   ID07                   
3   ID08   ID08
```

Desired:

```
    id1     id2            college_name
0   ID01   ID01             College1
1          ID03             College3
2   ID07                    College7
3   ID08   ID08             College8
```

Also, one thing about this data frame is that I am pretty sure the first 2 columns either are an exact match or one of them is empty. I would like to double-check if there is an instance where id1 and id2 are completely different numbers in the same row. How should I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Coalesce values from 2 columns into a single column in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38152389/coalesce-values-from-2-columns-into-a-single-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: The question I linked doesn't mention this, but to use `combine_first()`, you'll need to replace the blank entries with np.nan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backfill values from `id2` to `id1`. Extract the numbers. Convert to `int` then `str`.

Given:

```
    id1   id2
0  ID01  ID01
1   NaN  ID03
2  ID07   NaN
3  ID08  ID08
```

Doing:

```
df['college_name'] = 'College' + (df.bfill(axis=1)['id1']
                                    .str.extract('(\d+)')
                                    .astype(int)
                                    .astype(str))
```

Output:

```
    id1   id2 college_name
0  ID01  ID01     College1
1   NaN  ID03     College3
2  ID07   NaN     College7
3  ID08  ID08     College8
```

---

To check for rows where the ids are different:

Given:

```
    id1   id2
0  ID01  ID01
1   NaN  ID03
2  ID07   NaN
3  ID08  ID98
```

Doing:

```
print(df[df.id1.ne(df.id2) & df.id1.notna() & df.id2.notna()])
```

Output:

```
    id1   id2
3  ID08  ID98
```

Comment: Hi, I just edited my question to be more clear since you didn't really answer my question.

Comment: So I tried this, but it isn't working for me- I start off with no NA values, just empty values. Could this be the issue? When I try to add the na values, it doesn't work.

Comment: @youtube `df = df.replace('', np.nan)`