# Merge two dataframes one common column

Tags: python, pandas, merge, vlookup

I have two data frames, one with three columns and another with two columns. Two columns are common in both data frames:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1LXS.png)

I have to update the Marks column of `df1` from `df2` where the data is missing only and keep the existing value as same in the `df1`.

I have tried `pd.merge` but the result created a separate column which was not intended.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38152389/coalesce-values-from-2-columns-into-a-single-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Sir, I have to update data only with null values i.e.  hv to apply vlookup in the existing column (without creating a new column) only for the cells where value is absent.

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me:

```
df1['Mark'] = df1.Marks_x.combine_first(df1.Marks_y)   
df1['Marks_x'] = df1['Mark']    
df1 = df1.drop(['Marks_y', 'Mark'], axis=1)    
df1 = df1.rename(columns = {'Marks_x':'Marks'})
```